# How to define the length of SlidingUpPanelLayout from top?

Tags: android, xml

I have implemented the SlidingUpPanelLayout in my app. But I have to define the length of the SlidingUpPanelLayout from the top.

Here is my code

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="430dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="50dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/main">
```

Comment: umanoPanelHeight takes the height from the bottom which varies according to the phone size. I want to fix the height of the SlidingUpPanelLayout from the top.

Comment: why would you need to set the height from the top when you have it on bottom? do you want to align it on top?